# How do I make changes in Views from dev to stage to production environment?

Tags: views, database, importing-exporting

I am currently working on Production website. We are hosting our site in Acquia where we have Dev, Stage and Production environment.

I have question regarding making changes in Views Block in production.

If we make any changes in views in Dev environment, changes will not be push in Stage environment as I think views changes are done in the database.

How do I make changes or update my existing views in Production without redoing it from scratch.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you use Features?

Comment: This should be an affirmative, not a question, use [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features)

Comment: Features is a module which can convert the views settings into code. Then you can have version control for your changes and be able to push to the production.

Comment: @JimmyKo, mchar and heart.cooks.mind - Thank you so much for your help.